# Is it possible to access the html of a site with a 204 response code via java.net?

Tags: java, http, response

I am trying to read a website using the `java.net` package classes. The site has content, and i see it manually in html source utilities in the browser. When I get its response code and try to view the site using java, it connects successfully but interprets the site as one without content(204 code). What is going on and is it possible to get around this to view the html automatically.

thanks for your responses:
Do you need the URL?

here is the code:

```
   URL hef=new URL(the website); 
   BufferedReader kj=null;
   int kjkj=((HttpURLConnection)hef.openConnection()).getResponseCode();
   System.out.println(kjkj);
    String j=((HttpURLConnection)hef.openConnection()).getResponseMessage();
   System.out.println(j);
   URLConnection g=hef.openConnection();
   g.connect();

   try{
           kj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(g.getInputStream()));


     while(kj.readLine()!=null)
     {
         String y=kj.readLine();

         System.out.println(y);
      } 
   }

    finally
    {
         if(kj!=null)
        {
            kj.close();
         }
    }


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Assert than when manually accessing the site (with a web browser client) you are effectively getting a 200 return code
- Make sure that the HTTP request issued from the automated (java-based) logic is similar/identical to that of what is sent by an interactive web browser client. In particular, make sure the *User-Agent* is identical (some sites purposely alter their responses depending on the agent).
- You can use a packet sniffer, maybe something like [***Fiddler2***](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see exactly what is being sent and received to/from the server
- <strike>I'm not sure that the java.net package is robot-aware, but that could be a factor as well (can you check if the underlying site has robot.txt files).</strike>

Edit:
assuming you are using the java.net package's HttpURLConnection class, the "robot" hypothesis doesn't apply.
On the other hand you'll probably want to use the connection's setRequestProperty() method to prepare the desired HTTP header for the request (so they match these from the web browser client)
Maybe you can post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: this is exactly the info i am looking for. thanks and i believe the user-agent is the problem, and fiddler2 is useful.